# Объединение массивов в javascript

Tags: javascript

Объединить массивы без повторяющийся фамилий.Как это сделать с помощью деструктуризации?

```
const clients1 = ["Гилберт", "Сальваторе", "Пирс", "Соммерс", "Форбс", "Донован", "Беннет"];
const clients2 = ["Пирс", "Зальцман", "Сальваторе", "Майклсон"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Одной деструктуризацией не обойтись, но можно использовать `Set` - там ключи уникальны, и можно перевести значения массива в ключи и обратно в массив, что даст требуемый результат)

```js
const clients1 = ["Гилберт", "Сальваторе", "Пирс", "Соммерс", "Форбс", "Донован", "Беннет"];
const clients2 = ["Пирс", "Зальцман", "Сальваторе", "Майклсон"];


const result = [...new Set([...clients1, ...clients2])];
console.log(result);
```

[Подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)